# Java, Tengo hecha una funcion pero me da error cuando compila

Tags: java, funciones

Se trata de una función en la cual quiero que al escribir un array me devuelva su espejo es decir: {1,2,3} me devuelva : ¨{1,2,3,3,2,1}. creo que el resto del código esta bien pero al compilar me da el siguiente error:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem:
> The method imagentEspejo(int[]) is undefined for the type examen2019.

Este es el código.

```
public class examen2019 {
    static int[] imagenEspejo(int[] arr){
        int i;
        int[] result = new int[arr.length*2];
        
        for(i=0;i<=arr.length*2;i++){
            if( i<=arr.length){
                result[i]= arr[i];
            }else{
                
                result[i]= arr[i-arr.length];

            } 

        }return result;

    }
    public static void main(String[] args){

        int[] arr={1,2};
        System.out.println(imagentEspejo(arr));
    }
    
}
```

Comment: `System.out.println(imagentEspejo(arr));` fíjate en lo que has escrito... tu IDE debe estar marcándote un error ahí, puesto que has puesto `imagen**t**Espejo(arr)`. Es muy importante hacer caso a los avisos del IDE, no ignorarlos....

Comment: Madre mía ,vale muchas gracias no me había fijado en ese detalle.Gracias